# How to get the latest/last record with a group by clause with NHibernate Linq provider

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have used too much time (days) on this and I really hope someone can help me out.
I found a good [article on describing my problem](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/linq-how-to-get-the-latest-last-record-with-a-group-by-clause/) in a generic way so let's stick to it.

I am trying to build this query but NHibernate fails to build the correct sql and returns a sql query exception.

Column `vSagsAendring.Id` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause. It could not execute the following query:

```
select
    viewsagsae0_.Id as Id155_,
    viewsagsae0_.SagId as SagId155_,
    viewsagsae0_.JournalNr as JournalNr155_,
    viewsagsae0_.LbfNr as LbfNr155_,
    viewsagsae0_.OrgNr as OrgNr155_,
    viewsagsae0_.OrgNavn as OrgNavn155_,
    viewsagsae0_.AfdNavn as AfdNavn155_,
    viewsagsae0_.SagsType as SagsType155_,
    viewsagsae0_.Status as Status155_,
    viewsagsae0_.SagsbehandlerInit as Sagsbeh10_155_,
    viewsagsae0_.Dato as Dato155_,
    viewsagsae0_.JournalAktionType as Journal12_155_,
    viewsagsae0_.Beskrivelse as Beskriv13_155_,
    viewsagsae0_.Ekstern as Ekstern155_
from vSagsAendring viewsagsae0_
group by viewsagsae0_.SagId
```

```
var query = from p in _session.Query<ViewSagsAendring>()
            group p by p.SagId
            into grp
            select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.Dato).First();
```

This is another version also took from the article:

```
var query = from p in _session.Query<ViewSagsAendring>()
                    group p by p.SagId
                    into grp
                    let maxDato = grp.Max(g => g.Dato)
                    from p in grp
                    where p.Dato == maxDato
                    select p;
```

Comment: What version of NH are you using?

Comment: NHibernate version 3.3.3.4001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's have been a long journey, but now it's over. I hope that I can help someone else in the same situation by answering my own question.

```
var aendring = from sagsAendring in _session.Query<ViewSagsAendring>()
                       where sagsAendring.Dato ==
                       (
                          from innersagsAendring in _session.Query<ViewSagsAendring>()
                          where innersagsAendring.SagId == sagsAendring.SagId
                          select innersagsAendring.Dato
                       ).Max()
                       select sagsAendring;
var result = aendring.ToList();
```

And because you can chain linq statements you can build a linq filter like this

```
 if(Filters.VisInterneAendringer == false)
            query = query.Where(x => x.Ekstern == true);
 if (Filters.VisKunNyesteAendringer)
        {
            query = query.Where(sagsAendring => sagsAendring.Dato ==
                               (
                                   from innerSagsAendring in Session.Query<ViewSagsAendring>()                                                        where innerSagsAendring.SagId == sagsAendring.SagId
                                   select innerSagsAendring.Dato
                                ).Max());
        }

 return query;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your queries seem legit for LINQ in EntityFramework.
I'm not sure about hibernate, you might try to use QueryOver API instead of Query

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html